# Does Python cache loaded files?

Tags: python, performance, caching

I notice that recently-loaded files load vastly quicker when requested again - *even after the file is deleted and RAM is freed up*. I doubt it's precisely caching, as RAM should remain the same - but the load speed difference is clear. This persists for up to 10 consecutive loads of different files - after which the effect ceases. Code below.

What, exactly, is this behavior - and if it has an adverse effect on performance, how to prevent it?

---

```python
# RAM 52% (Spyder & TaskManager readings)
t0 = time()
x0  = load_mat(filepath0) # RAM 60%
print('0: ' + str(time() - t0))
del x0  # RAM 52%

...


t0 = time()
x9  = load_mat(filepath9) # RAM 60%
print('9: ' + str(time() - t0))
del x9  # RAM 52%

t0 = time()
x0_ = load_mat(filepath0) # RAM 60%
print('0_: ' + str(time() - t0))
del x0_ # RAM 52%

...
```

**0:**  5.798      0_:  **0.501**
**1:**  5.541      1_:  **0.539**
**2:**  6.076      2_:  **0.575**
**3:**  5.785      3_:  **0.581**
**4:**  5.772      4_:  **0.521**
**5:**  5.692      5_:  **0.513**
**6:**  5.838      6_:  **0.529**
**7:**  5.711      7_:  **0.513**
**8:**  5.677      8_:  **0.509**
**9:**  5.997      9_:  **0.514**

*(Interesting event at 11 loaded: time taken = 2.47 sec - neither 5.5, nor 0.5)*

---

```python
## FUNCTIONS/MODULES USED
from time import time
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np

def load_mat(filepath):
    return np.asarray(loadmat(filepath)['data']).astype('float32')
```

Comment: The OS has a filesystem level cache.

Comment: @KlausD. How does it cache 4GB's worth while keeping RAM free?

Comment: The OS file caching is not the right topic to discuss here. How it works is also very depended on your OS.